# How to search array of structs for a string(name) and return info for that string(name)?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct

With this program, when i type in a name nothing is returned.

How would I fix this?

There are 1000 lines of info that looks like this:

> 114680858 19670607 Matilda Vincent MI
>
> 114930037 19471024 Desdemona Hanover ID
>
> 115550206 19790110 Xanadu Perlman ND
>
> 116520629 19630921 Alexander Hall SD
>
> 117050976 19301016 David Lamprey GA
>
> 119610646 19650202 Thomas Porlock IL
>
> 120330928 19621126 Cary Cartman NC
>
> etc......

Code:

```
struct employees
{
    int ss_number;//social security
    int dob;//date of birth YYYY/MM/DD Ex.) 19870314=1987/03/14
    string f_name;
    string l_name;
    string state; //state of residence
};

void read_file()//read file into array of 1000 structs
{
    ifstream data("/home/www/class/een118/labs/database1.txt");
    employees array[1000]
    if(!data.fail())
    {
        int i;
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            data>>array[i].ss_number
                >>array[i].dob
                >>array[i].f_name
                >>array[i].l_name
                >>array[i].state;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            cout<<array[i].ss_number>>" "<<array[i].dob>>" "<<array[i].f_name>>" "<<
            array[i].l_name>>" "<<array[i].state;
        }
    }
}

void print_person(employees e)
{
    cout<<e.ss_number>>" "<<e.dob>>" "<<e.f_name>>" "<<e.l_name>>" "<<e.state;
}

void search(employees array[])//type in name and get that persons ss_number,dob etc...
{
    string first;
    string last;
    cout<<"Enter name";
    cin>>first>>last;
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        if(array[i].f_name==first && array[i].l_name==last)
        {
            print_person(array[i]);
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    employees array[10];
    read_file();
    search(array);
}
//  ...
```

Comment: What were the values of the variables when you used the debugger?

Comment: Remember that `==` performs a case sensitive comparison with strings.  You may want to convert to all lowercase or all uppercase before comparing.

Comment: Your `cout` lines are full of `>>` .. I don't even

Answer (score 1):

There are two arrays.  One is in `main`, the other is in `read_file`.  They have the same name but are different sizes.

The array in `read_file` has no relationship to the array in `main`.  You passed the array to `search` but not to `read_file`.  I suggest you pass the array to `read_file` by reference and remove the array declaration in `read_file`.

Better yet, eliminate the array and use `std::vector`.  It would be `std::vector<employees>`.

**Edit 1: Searching the array**
In your `search` function you will need to pass two additional parameters:  array capacity and the number of records in the array.  If you used `std::vector<employees>`, you could get the number of employees in the array by:

```
  number_of_employees = array.size();
```

The `for` loop would use iterators:

```
std::vector<employees>::const_iterator iter;
for (iter = array.begin(); iter != array.end(); ++iter)
{
  // process array slot by dereferencing it:
    employee e = *iter;
    cout << e << "\n"; // This could happen if you overloaded operator <<
}
```

Otherwise, with an array, your loop would look like:

```
void search(employees array[], unsigned int capacity, unsigned int employees_in_array)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < employees_in_array; ++i)
  {
    cout << array[i];
  }
}
```

A nice improvement is that this search function doesn't hardcode the size.  So you can change the size from 10 (in `main`) to 1000 without modifying the `search` function.

If you sort your container, you can use a binary search.
See:  `std::binary_search, std::find, std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound`